# Building a case to migrate away from the use of tools or technologies in ways they were never intended to be used

Tags: migration, misuse

I've seen some pretty strange use of technology.

For example, one place I worked was using [Microsoft Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) to send real time streaming VoIP data between servers.

I work as a consultant and many times the person responsible for these decisions is no longer at the company. The problem is that from the perspective of non-technical people it works just fine. The problem comes when needing to add functionality and fix bugs in systems like this.

If you are in a situation like this how would you build a case to spend time migrating to a more suitable technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a business case.  In my experience, "This is an unsupported use" makes a great business case.  Business people understand what it means to be [unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788707.aspx) by a [vendor](http://www.microsoft.com), and like to avoid that as much as the next person.  Explain what risks or downsides the issue has to them (not to you).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to put in terms of concrete benefits:
- saved money 
- less risks
- easy of development or maintenance (which should save money!)

If there are not tangible benefits then there is NO REASON to change!